# Cauchy and contracting sequence problem

Tags: limits

[image]

For part 1 (a) I think there is a mistake and increasing should not be there.
Nevertheless I am having some issues with it.

I said :
$ 0 $ EDIT :should be $ 2 \leq a_{n+1} \leq 4 $   which is easy to show. Then $ a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=(3+\frac{2}{a_{n+1}} )-(3+\frac{2}{a_n} ) = \frac{ 2(a_n-a_{n+1})}{(a_n)(a_{n+a})} $
Now using inequality and modulus we get $ |a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq|\frac {2(a_{n+1}-a_n)}{16}|\leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}-a_n| $ I don't think its correct though. Where am I going wrong?

And for question 2. I am confused about it as well . If we say $ a_n $ is Cauchy and with limit $ l $ does it it automatically mean the result? How can I show it if not.
Cheers.

Comment: These should be two separate questions.

Comment: Note that $ 2\leq a_n \leq 4 $.

Comment: Yeah that is right. But does it make any difference?

Comment: Of course it does. I spooted my mistake. Thanks!